# HTTP: shutdown socket for writing after sending the request?

Tags: http, sockets

How is a socket used by an HTTP client properly closed after transmitting the request? Or does it have to remain open (bidirectionally) until the complete response has been received? If so, how is the end of the request body determined by the server?

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4, closing the socket is not an option for a request. That doesn't sound logical to me - why should a half-closed TCP connection be a problem for the server, if the client doesn't try to transmit anything after closing its half of the socket? The client can still receive data after all.

It seems to me that shutting down the write part of a socket would be a very practical way of letting the server know that the request has been finished. http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html#disconnecting even specifically mentions that use case.

If that's really the wrong way to do it, what's the alternative? Do I really always have to send a "Content-length" or use chunked transport to enable the server to properly find the end of a request? How does that work for requests with unknown body length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is specifically designed to allow sending data with an unknown body length, for both requests and responses.  The end of the data is determined by receiving a chunk whose payload size is 0.  If you do not send a `chunked` request, then you must send a `Content-Length` instead.

Comment: So it is mandatory to either use chunked transfer encoding or send a "Content-Length" header for all requests with a request body? I'm aware that it would be a wise thing to do, but is that actually specified somewhere in the standard?

Comment: If the request has a body, then you must include enough information for the server to determine the size of the body.  Read RFC 2616 sections 4.3 (Message Body) and 4.4 (Message Length).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this?:

> Closing the connection cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body, since that would leave no possibility for the server to send back a response.

I think the text is talking about full close, you can do a half(write)-close. I'm not sure that's a HTTP compilant way of doing it, but I would think most servers will accept it.

Regarding your second question, simply use chunked encoding:

> All HTTP/1.1 applications that receive entities MUST accept the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6), thus allowing this mechanism to be used for messages when the message length cannot be determined in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is the passage I'm referring to. So you'd say that it would be safe to do a half-close? Thats what I hoped; I didn't want to implement chunked transfer coding for a simple HTTP server.

Comment: well, my experience is that servers are a lot more error tolerant than the standard specifies (probably to wrok with crappy clients...). It sounds like you are writing your on server and clients.. In that case, if you don't have HTTP proxies in your path you can do whatever you want. It's not a nice thing to do, but it works ;)